# Django Differentiating Children in Queryset

Tags: django, inheritance

I have a model called "Block"

```
class Block(models.Model):
zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
order = models.IntegerField()
weight = models.IntegerField()
block_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['order']

def __str__(self):
    return "Block "+str(self.order)
```

The Block object has children inheriting from it. ImageBlock, VideoBlock, etc... I'll be adding more as the project goes on

```
# Children of Block Object
class TextBlock(Block):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

class ImageBlock(Block):
    content = models.ImageField(blank=True)

class VideoBlock(Block):
    content = models.FileField(blank=True)
```

I need to perform operations on the blocks depending on their order. As in,

Render TextBlock1
Render ImageBlock1
Render TextBlock2

I query all of these objects with something along the lines of Block.objects.all() and then iterate through them. As I do so, how do I differentiate which of my objects each of them are?

As in:

```
blockset = Block.objects.all()
for block in blockset:
    if (**some way of differentiating if it's a TextBlock**):
        print("This is a text block!")
```

Any idea of how I might go about doing this?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is ``block_type``? Do you not use that to determine the type?

Comment: This may be more or less than you need but you might be interested in the django_model_utils pacakge so you can do stuff like [this](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Content Types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes) on the Parent model if you did not know the name of the class you wanted to get. For example:

(not tested)

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Block(models.Model):
   zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
   order = models.IntegerField()
   weight = models.IntegerField()
   block_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, editable=False)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.block_type = self._block_type()
        super(Block, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

   def __block_type(self):
        return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(self))

    def cast(self):
        return self.block_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=self.pk)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Also note the abstract base class this means the model won't be created in the database. The abstract fields will be added to those of the child class i.e.

```
class TextBlock(Block):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

However, you can't query the abstract base class in this example. If this is what you want to do then simple add a lookup on your base class.

```
 TEXT = 'TXT'
 IMAGE = 'IMG'
 VIDEO = 'VID'
 BLOCK_CHOICES = (
        (TEXT, 'Text Block'),
        (IMAGE, 'Image Block'),
        (VIDEO, 'Video Block'),
    )

class Block(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    block_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=BLOCK_CHOICES)
```

Then query: `Block.objects.filter(block_type='Text Block')`

Or in your example:

```
blockset = Block.objects.all()
for block in blockset:
    if block.block_type == "Text Block":
        print("This is a text block!")
```

Comment: Hmm yeah I had been hoping to get rid of the block_type field of the base object, but you're right that I couldn't query an abstract class (and without that, ContentType just returns the name of my parent Block object.) 

Anyway, thanks for the clarification, and for introducing me to the Content Type function!

Comment: Not a problem, I hope it helps.